# SQL Server Reporting Services - Remove extra empty space put after a subreport when exporting to Word

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Report Builder 3.0 and my main report contains a big table with 2 columns and multiple rows. At some point the two columns are merged into one and contain a subreport. I use 3 subreports consecutively. 
My problem is when exporting to Word. After the first and the second subreport Word adds a pretty big white space.
I've tried to figure out if the white space comes from the end of subreports 1 and 2, or from the beginning of subreports 2 and 3.
I have deleted all the margins from the subreports and also set the page size so it would be accordingly to the page size of the main report.
Basically, I am trying to figure out ugly white spaces when exporting a table containing subreports in Word and how to get rid of it.
I hope my desperation has been sensed and absolutely every suggestion will be extremely welcomed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for any suggestion...

A tip I once read for determining what is creating space in a report: set the background color for the various elements: a different non-white color for each element. Then, hopefully, you can see what is causing the space in the exported document. Also see if different format exports have this problem, or if it's really unique to just Word.

Comment: I have tried to add different background color to every element and I did not leave any object without a non-white color.The empty space after subreports still appears and it is still white. Also I forgot to mention that when exporting to PDF it works just fine, but I need to export as a .doc to

Answer (score 0):

You have a new page after a group or subreport set. Therefore, the rest of the page is whitespace. Check for these and run your report.